# How to open Youtube video link inside android app? ( Without calling Youtube APP)

Tags: java, android

I want to display an Youtube video inside my activity, without open any third apps.
Something like Telegram do.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to integrate [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Setup Youtube API from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup)